# Array of strings to be put in to Vector

Tags: java

I have this problem in the below code as it does not run but generated nullpointer exception. What i am trying to do here is get an input an array of strings then spit it but comma and then pass it to Integer type and then store it in a vector. Then get the maximum number from that array. Code shows no errors but hard to find whats wrong.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Splitting {

  /**
  * @param   
  */

protected int[] temp;
Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<Integer>();

public void split(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
      String[] str;
      str = input.split(",");
      temp = new int[str.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            vec.add(temp[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(vec);
    Collections.sort(vec);

    System.out.println(vec);
    Collections.max(vec);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Splitting obj = new Splitting();

    obj.split("12,65,21,23,89,67,12");



}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to *create* an array. Replace

```
temp = null;
```

with

```
temp = new int[str.length];
```

---

Another slight problem: you test `input != null` in a while loop *after* you've used it for the split. So if your method is called with a `null` value, you'll get a NPE even before the while statement is executed. You can remove the while statement and add a test

```
if (input == null) {
   // return or throw exception
}
```

at the beginning of your method.

---

You're close with your code - I think I can show a reference implementation to compare:

```
public void split(String input) {
  if (input == null) {
     // if the input is null, print a message and return
     System.out.println("Input must not be null");
     return;
  }

  String[] numbers = input.split(",");  // changed the name to show the content
  int[] temp = new int[numbers.length];

  for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     try {
        temp[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
     } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // if a number can't be parsed, print a message and return
        System.out.println("Input contains an illegal entry (non-integer value");
        return;
     }
     vec.add(temp[i]);
  }
  System.out.println(vec);
  Collections.sort(vec);

  System.out.println(vec);
  Collections.max(vec);
}
```

Comment: @ Andreas_D Thanks for that. I am a beginner in Java but I did the changes what you said that I should do according to what I understood but it seems still not working. sorry

Comment: @Splitter - easy to fix: change the condition at the beginning to `input != null` - you want the next block being executed *if the input is not null* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in this line `temp = null;` . Remove this line. This is throwing your NPE. You are trying to access a field that is null.

Instead declare temp inside the split method.

`int [] temp = new int [str.length];`

Comment: @ CoolBeans - This part is I am afraid wrong "new int [input.length];"

Comment: @Splitter Sorry, I picked the wrong variable name. It should be str.length.

Answer (score 1):

CoolBeans and AndreasD have pointed out that `temp` should not be initialized to null. Let me add, temp shouldn't exist as an array, period. You are creating a duplicate structure, once as the array `temp` and the other time as the Vector vec.

So, here are some possible changes. `temp` just becomes an int (not array) and everywhere you have `temp[i]`, replace with `temp`. Or, get rid of `temp` entirely and just have `vec.add(Integer.parseInt(str[i]));`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
String[] strArr = "12,65,21,23,89,67,12".split(",");
int[] intArr = new int[strArr.length];

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
}

Ints.max(intArr); // 89, with Google Guava Ints.max
```